# How do you use the Gradle Docker Plugin to build a docker image with a provided Dockerfile in Windows?

Tags: docker, gradle

Using the [Gradle Docker plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/), I am trying to build a Docker image with a Dockerfile I already created.  I got this far

```
plugins {
    id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '6.4.0'
}

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerPushImage

task dockerBuildImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    inputDir = projectDir
    images.add('trajano/cloud-auth')
}

task dockerPushImage(type: DockerPushImage) {
    dependsOn dockerBuildImage
    images.add('trajano/cloud-auth')
}

task build {
    dependsOn tasks.dockerPushImage
}
```

I am getting this error though

```
Building image using context 'D:\p\spring-cloud-demo\cloud-auth'.
Using images 'trajano/cloud-auth'.

Error during callback
com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Is your Docker daemon running? If so and you are on Windows, try enabling "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" in Settings -> General.

Comment: Didn't try that far, I exposed the port a different way but then I lose my authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the command line to do the build, here's my `build.gradle` file where I commented out the plugin code.  It solves my immediate problem for the builds, but it is more ideal than exposing 2375.

```
plugins {
//    id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '6.4.0'
}

//import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
//import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerPushImage
task dockerBuildImage(type: Exec) {
//    inputDir = projectDir
//    images.add('trajano/cloud-auth')
    commandLine "docker", "build", ".", "-t", "trajano/cloud-auth"
}

task dockerPushImage(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn dockerBuildImage
    commandLine "docker", "push", "trajano/cloud-auth"
}

task build {
    dependsOn tasks.dockerPushImage
}
```